# How to adjust this table?

Tags: tables

I'd just like to adjust this table here. Something in the code is putting the table in the top of the page instead below the subsection designed. Moreover if possible, add some horizontal and vertical space between lines. I thank you for any help here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}                       % for codes
\usepackage{amsmath}                        % for matrices 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}                           % for flowcharts
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Derivatives and Integrals}

        \begin{description}

        \item[Derivatives]

        \item \hspace{0.5in} Derivatives are used to analyse the rate in which a variable changes its value related with another, if it is fast, slow or non-existent. Some examples are: the body response due to a drug dosage or the cost of a production due to the quantity of any special material used.

        \item \hspace{0.5in} The derivative of a function $f(x)$ related to the variable $x$ is the                                         function $f'$ which value in $x$ is defined by:

        $$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

        \item \hspace{0.5in} One of the most important use of the derivatives is to know in what point              $c$ a function reach its maximum and minimum values, which can be found by:

        $$f'(c) = 0$$ 

        \item[Useful Derivatives]

        \end{description}        

        \begin{center}
        \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{l l}

        $y = u^n \Rightarrow y' = n \ u^{n-1} \ u'$ & $y = u^v \Rightarrow y' = v \ u^{v-1} \ u' + u^v \ (ln \ u) \ v'$ \\
        $y = uv \Rightarrow y' = vu'+uv'$ & $y = sin \ u \Rightarrow y' = u' \ cos \ u$ \\
        $y = \displaystyle{\frac{u}{v}} \Rightarrow y' = \displaystyle{\frac{vu'-uv'}{v^2}}$ & $y = cos \ u \Rightarrow y' = -u' \ sin \ u$ \\
        $y = a^u \Rightarrow y' = a^u \ (ln \ a) \ u'$ & $y = tan \ u \Rightarrow y' = u' \ sec^2u$ \\
        $y = log_au \Rightarrow y' = \displaystyle{\frac{u'}{u}} log_a e$ & $y = sec \ u \Rightarrow y' = u' \ sec \ u  \ tan \ u$

        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the table, try adding `[h]` after `\begin{table}`, as indicated in any basic documentation. [edited: misread the question] Note that it would probably have taken less time to look for the answers in the web than write this question!

Comment: @anderstood when I put the \begin{table}[h] the table went to last page of the document.

Comment: Drop the entire `table` environment, and just keep the `tabular` inside `center`.

Comment: The macro `\displaystyle` doesn't take an argument and thus also affects what comes *after* the math atom (math molecule?) encased by the subsequent `{...}`. I'd simply omit the pair of braces. If it's really important to limit the scope of `\displaystyle` (which I don't think is the case in the present examples), I'd write `{\displaystyle ...}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my suggestion on setting the information you've provided:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,indentfirst}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}

\section{Derivatives and Integrals}

\subsection{Derivatives}

Derivatives are used to analyse the rate in which a variable changes its value related with another, if it is fast, slow or non-existent. Some examples are: the body response due to a drug dosage or the cost of a production due to the quantity of any special material used.

The derivative of a function~$f(x)$ related to the variable~$x$ is the function~$f'$ which value in~$x$ is defined by:
\[
  f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
\]

One of the most important use of the derivatives is to know in what point~$c$ a function reach its maximum and minimum values, which can be found by:
\[
  f'(c) = 0
\]

\subsection{Useful Derivatives}

\[
  \begin{array}{l @{\quad\Rightarrow\quad} l @{\qquad} l @{\quad\Rightarrow\quad} l}
    y = u^n & y' = n u^{n-1} u' & y = u^v & y' = v u^{v-1} u' + u^v (\ln u) v' \\
    y = uv & y' = vu' + uv' & y = \sin u & y' = u' \cos u \\
    y = \dfrac{u}{v} & y' = \dfrac{vu'-uv'}{v^2} & y = \cos u & y' = -u' \sin u \\
    y = a^u & y' = a^u (\ln a) u' & y = \tan u & y' = u' \sec^2u \\
    y = \log_a u & y' = \dfrac{u'}{u} \log_a e & y = \sec u & y' = u' \sec u \tan u
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note how I've used the math operators `\tan`, `\sin`, `\cos`, `\sec`, `\log` and `\ln` and didn't force the spacing around the math variables. Let TeX do this for you.

Also, instead of the cumberson `description` itemization, set things according to sectional units. You can turn the numbering on/off by setting `secnumdepth` (to 0; number only up to chapter, which you don't have in an article).

Finally, there is no need for a `table` environment in order to set a `tabular`. Instead, since you want the "mathematical" `tabular` horizontally centred, I've used a display math `\[`...`\]` with an `array`.

Comment: More than perfectly answered!! Thank you even to the adjustments I was struggling with!!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a suggestion that pertains just to the table part of your example code. I suggest creating a table, providing a header row and stripping away all `y =`, `y' =`, and `\Rightarrow` matter to let the reader focus on the essentials. The material in the `array` columns is set in `\displaystyle` mode automatically, and the look of TeX's displayed equations is simulated by setting `\arraystretch` to `1.5` (default: `1.0`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l} % automatic \displaystyle
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}  % simulate spacing of displayed equations
  \begin{array}{@{} L @{\quad} L @{\qquad\quad} L @{\quad} L @{}}
    $Function$  & $Derivative$          & $Function$ & $Derivative$\\
    u^n         & n u^{n-1} u'          & u^v        & v u^{v-1} u' + u^v (\ln u) v' \\
    uv          & vu' + uv'             & \sin u     & u' \cos u \\
    \frac{u}{v} & \frac{vu'-uv'}{v^2}   & \cos u     & -u' \sin u \\
    a^u         & a^u (\ln a) u'        & \tan u     & u' \sec^2u \\
    \log_a u    & \frac{u'}{u} \log_a e & \sec u     & u' \sec u \tan u \\
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```